# Python noob: manipulating arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, probability

I have already asked a few questions on here about this same topic, but I'm really trying not to disappoint the professor I'm doing research with.  This is my first time using Python and I may have gotten in a little over my head.

Anyways, I was sent a file to read and was able to using this command:

```
SNdata = numpy.genfromtxt('...', dtype=None, 
usecols (0,6,7,8,9,19,24,29,31,33,34,37,39,40,41,42,43,44), 
names ['sn','off1','dir1','off2','dir2','type','gal','dist',
'htype','d1','d2','pa','ai','b','berr','b0','k','kerr'])
```

`sn` is just an array of the names of a particular supernova; `type` is an array of the type of supernovae it is (Ia or II), etc.

One of the first things I need to do is simply calculate the probabilities of certain properties given the SN type (Ia or II).

For instance, the column `htype` is the morphology of a galaxy (given as an integer 1=elliptical to 8=irregular).  I need to calculate the probability of an elliptical given a TypeIa and an elliptical given TypeII, for all of the integers to up to 8.

For ellipticals, I know that I just need the number of elements that have `htype = 1 and type = Ia` divided by the total number of elements of `type = Ia`.  And then the number of elements that have `htype = 1 and type = II` divided by the total number of elements that have `type = II`.

I just have no idea how to write code for this.  I was planning on finding the total number of each type first and then running a for loop to find the number of elements that have a certain `htype` given their `type` (Ia or II).

Could anyone help me get started with this?  If any clarification is needed, let me know.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Check out the http://pandas.pydata.org/ library. It'll help you in the long run. It would be quite helpful to people reading your question if you could include some sample data. You could simplify this question a lot by cutting it down to just the columns you are asking about and then add the rest of the stuff to your own code once you have things figured out...

Answer (score 4):

Numpy supports boolean array operations, which will make your code fairly straightforward to write. For instance, you could do:

```
htype_sums = {}
for htype_number in xrange(1,9):
  htype_mask = SNdata.htype == htype_number
  Ia_mask = SNdata.type == 'Ia'
  II_mask = SNdata.type == 'II'

  Ia_sum = (htype_mask & Ia_mask).sum() / Ia_mask.sum()
  II_sum = (htype_mask & II_mask).sum() / II_mask.sum()
  htype_sums[htype_number] = (Ia_sum, II_sum)
```

Each of the `_mask` variables are boolean arrays, so when you sum them you count the number of elements that are `True`.

Comment: I was able to get correct sums if I were to them individually.  However, when I run the for loop, my sum is only for `htype = 10`.  How do I get 8 different sums?

Comment: @user2909019: I edited my answer to store the results in a dictionary. This might not be the best structure for your program, but it should make it easy to inspect your results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.Counter` to count needed observations.

For example,

```
from collections import Counter
types_counter = Counter(row['type'] for row in data)
```

will give you desired counts of sn `types`.

```
htypes_types_counter = Counter((row['type'], row['htype']) for row in data)
```

counts for morphology and types. Then, to get your evaluation for ellipticals, just divide

```
1.0*htypes_types_counter['Ia', 1]/types_counter['Ia']
```